# Issue with my AWS lambda function in invoking a command inside EC2 using SSM

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I am trying to run a simple echo command in my EC2 machine, from my lambda function , using AWS System manager.

Below is my code

```
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
    instance_id = 'i-**************'  
    document_name = 'AWS-RunPowerShellScript'
    command = 'echo "Hello from Lambda!"'

    response = ssm_client.send_command(
      InstanceIds=[instance_id],
      DocumentName=document_name,
      Parameters={
        'commands': [command],
      }
    )

    print(response)
```

Please note:

I have installed System manager in my EC2
I can see the System manager showing the EC2 instance as target instance enter image description here
Edited

But the command doesnot print 'Hello from lambda' in the function logs. when I click test button.The output is as below.

```
Test Event Name ge_test

Response null
```

**Function Logs**

```
START RequestId: 73608520-e238-4cf6-a18d-8da0067368f5 Version: $LATEST
{'Command': {'CommandId': '9e93360d-948d-4328-87e1-69fb8c46117a', 'DocumentName': 'AWS-RunPowerShellScript', 'DocumentVersion': '$DEFAULT', 'Comment': '', 'ExpiresAfter': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 18, 6, 29, 48, 706000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Parameters': {'commands': ['echo "Hello from Lambda!"']}, 'InstanceIds': ['i-023a94dcbd37108fc'], 'Targets': [], 'RequestedDateTime': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 18, 4, 29, 48, 706000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'Status': 'Pending', 'StatusDetails': 'Pending', 'OutputS3Region': 'ap-south-1', 'OutputS3BucketName': '', 'OutputS3KeyPrefix': '', 'MaxConcurrency': '50', 'MaxErrors': '0', 'TargetCount': 1, 'CompletedCount': 0, 'ErrorCount': 0, 'DeliveryTimedOutCount': 0, 'ServiceRole': '', 'NotificationConfig': {'NotificationArn': '', 'NotificationEvents': [], 'NotificationType': ''}, 'CloudWatchOutputConfig': {'CloudWatchLogGroupName': '', 'CloudWatchOutputEnabled': False}, 'TimeoutSeconds': 3600, 'AlarmConfiguration': {'IgnorePollAlarmFailure': False, 'Alarms': []}, 'TriggeredAlarms': []}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '040ca2de-694d-45bf-9b04-538bd37763a3', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Thu, 18 May 2023 04:29:48 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '920', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '040ca2de-694d-45bf-9b04-538bd37763a3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
END RequestId: 73608520-e238-4cf6-a18d-8da0067368f5
REPORT RequestId: 73608520-e238-4cf6-a18d-8da0067368f5  Duration: 1630.37 ms    Billed Duration: 1631 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 71 MB  Init Duration: 256.71 ms

Request ID
73608520-e238-4cf6-a18d-8da0067368f5
```

Comment: What does the SSM run command log show?